# Unbind & Bind tablesorter with pagination (Deactivate and activate the jquery plugin)

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, binding

I am using tablesorter http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm for my dynamic html table, I am facing issues with paginations as for some reason it still holds onto the pagination values from initialization.

On a button click, I need to remove the plugin's (Tablesorter's paging and sorting) hold on the table and then after I get the databack I rebind the plugin.

How Do I go about binding and rebinding the tablesorter plugin. Will unbinding release all initialized values in the plugin?

This would deactivate the hold of the plugin on the data and create a hold on the fresh set of data.

P.S: I do have a way to find out when the new set of table rows are available to apply the plugin, only unsure about the binding unbinding part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made this change on the tablesorter.pager.js file to get where i needed to go.

```
                 $(config.cssNext,pager).unbind('click');
                 $(config.cssPrev,pager).unbind('click');
                 $(config.cssFirst,pager).unbind('click');
                 $(config.cssLast,pager).unbind('click');
```

The code goes before.

```
                $(config.cssFirst,pager).click(function() {
                    moveToFirstPage(table);
                    return false;});
```